# How do I root an LG Phoenix 2?

Tags: rooting, lg-phoenix-2

I put Kingroot and many other rooting apps on my laptop and phone and all say failed it's a LG Phoenix 2 6.0 marshmallow please help,I did everything to root and still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no Root method out A.T.M. Kingroot has gotten 18059 requests (time of 9-11-16 2:34AM) so they might work on it soon